# Triggered pipeline uses different commit as triggering pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am struggling with the configuration of pipelines in Azure DevOps. I have the following situation:

- Same repository, branch develop.
- Pipeline A triggers pipeline B.
- Pipeline A definition:

```
# PIPELINE-A
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
pr: none

name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)__$(Build.SourceVersion)__$(Date:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm)

jobs:
  - job: Test
    pool:
      name: 'Default'
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Simulate 3 min. task
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo $(Build.SourceBranchName)
            echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
            sleep 180
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

- Pipeline B definition:

```
# PIPELINE-B
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: PIPELINE-A
      source: PIPELINE-A
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - develop

name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)__$(Build.SourceVersion)__$(Date:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm)

jobs:
  - job: Test
    pool:
      name: 'Default'
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Simulate task
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo $(Build.SourceBranchName)
            echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
            echo $(resources.pipeline.PIPELINE-A.sourceBranch)
            echo $(resources.pipeline.PIPELINE-A.sourceCommit)
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

If push 2 commits to develop, let´s say c1 and c2, I see that pipeline A is correctly triggered with 2 different runs, one for c1 and another for c2.

After completion of c1 in pipeline A, pipeline B is correctly triggered, but pipeline B has as Build.SourceVersion the value c2 (latest commit in develop branch) instead of c1. Moreover, resources.pipeline.PIPELINE-A.sourceCommit has the correct value c1 (the value that I was expecting for Build.SourceVersion in pipeline B).

After completion of c2 in pipeline A, pipeline is again correctly triggered and this time Build.SourceVersion and resources.pipeline.PIPELINE-A.sourceCommit have both c2 (that is correct because c2 is the last commit in develop branch).

Even if I trigger manually pipeline A for commit c1, pipeline B gets triggered but, again, with commit c2.

With this behavior we see several problems:

- At the web page of pipeline B all the runs show c2 as commit (last commit of branch) and is impossible to distinguish between pipeline A runs for commits c1 and c2.
- The checked out code is always the code of the commit c2.

Am I missing something? Jenkins handles this without any problem and it would trigger 2 different executions in pipeline B (one for c1 and another for c2).

Please note that `trigger:batch: true` is not an option because we want to have different concurrent builds for different commits.

Many thanks in advance for your help. Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with your yaml script but it works well on my side:

This is my pipeline-A:
[image]

And this is my pipeline-B:
[image]

So the issue may not be related to yaml script. Here are some troubleshooting advice:

1. Check the UI triggers. Please go to the edit page of your pipeline and click on the three dots button on the top right corner and select "triggers". Make sure that the option "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" is **unchecked** and no triggers are set in "Build completion" part.
2. I suggest you to create two new pipelines to check whether they can work to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi! many thanks for your response. I have checked your first point and everything was ok in the UI. I also deleted the pipelines and created new ones and, every time I trigger pipeline A with commit c1, pipeline B stills shows commit c2 at Build.SourceVersion (resources.pipeline.PIPELINE-A.sourceCommit shows commit c1 tough).